# Cron jobs with laravel using hostinger

Tags: php, laravel, cron, hosting

I had problem setting up cron jobs to send automated emails under hostinger server.
I tested out the automated email function through smtp under local environment using php artisan schedule:work to run the scheduled task.
The email is sent out without a problem.
Then i created a script in my public folder following this tutorial [tutorial](https://support.hostinger.com/en/articles/5646919-how-to-set-up-a-cron-job-with-special-characters-at-hostinger)

The cron job config is

```
/bin/sh /home/u765133174/domains/eurofinsmy.net/public_html/eurotracks/public/script.sh
```

and the script.sh is

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /home/u765133174/public_html/eurotracks/public && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

What did i did wrong? My guess is there's something wrong with the script but I couldn't quite figured how. The automated email just wouldnt send out after hosting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same problem on hostinger. From that I have resolved with one trick inside project.

I have created get route for cron execution and created a php file on root path of project.

Ex : in **web.php** create one route of type get form call cron like

```
Route::get('/cronsStartToWorkEmailSend', function () {
    \Artisan::call('emailsending:cron');
    return true;
});
```

In root path of project create one file called as **cronsStartToWorkEmailSend.php** and add a code for curl call for cron job run.

```
<?php

$url = 'https://your_project_domain/cronsStartToWorkEmailSend';

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

$data = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
  
?>
```

*And Now you can register cron job with **type php selection** from hostinger to call your **cronsStartToWorkEmailSend.php** file*

[image]

So basically what happens from this code structure.

1. When php file called via daemons on server on regular interval of time **cronsStartToWorkEmailSend.php** will call.
2. When **cronsStartToWorkEmailSend.php** call at that time our route **cronsStartToWorkEmailSend** will call.
3. When route **cronsStartToWorkEmailSend** will call at that time with help of this command **\Artisan::call('emailsending:cron')**  our cron will be triggered.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried setting up the through your way. https://your_project_domain/cronsStartToWorkEmailSend is working. If i input it in my browser, the email is sent immediately. The hostinger config is pointing to the correct path too, i added a ```echo "hello world\n";``` and it appears in the hostinger output. However, when combined into hostinger cron jobs, it still wasn't sending the emails. Is there any more factors that is affecting it?

Comment: is curl available for hosting shared hosting?

Comment: Yes it is available

Comment: I had a login feature regarding the website. Im guessing could it be the cron job needs username and password? If so, how do i input it in curl method?

Comment: I remove the routes away from the middleware. Now it works! thanks for the help.